# Windows: Docker can't access internet on corporate proxy

Tags: windows, docker, kong

I am running kong in Docker which is running on windows, now when i am on private network Docker unable to access internet. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your company is blocking it on your private network. Only thing you can do is try a proxy/vpn client.